# AttributeError when calling a function

Tags: python

I'm trying to make something that displays some messages depending on the time but I get the following error when I try to call the function.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "autodrive.py", line 31, in <module>
    goodbye()
  File "autodrive.py", line 19, in goodbye
    now = datetime.now()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'now'

import datetime
import random
import re 
import sys

def goodbye():
    now = datetime.now()
    now_time = now.time()

    bye = ['byee', 'see u', 'see you', 'au revoir']
    night = ['goodnight', 'gn', 'bye', 'sleep well', 'bonne nuit']

    if now_time >= time(21,30) or now_time <= time(4,00):
        print random.choice(night)

    if now_time >= time(4,00) or now_time <= time(21,30):
        print random.choice(bye)

goodbye()
```

Comment: it's `datetime.datetime.now()` not `datetime.now()`

Comment: (Trying `dir(datetime)` would have been a good first step toward investigating this)

Answer (score 2):

You imported the module, `datetime`. That module contains a class, also called `datetime`, which has a classmethod called `now`. You need to reference the whole thing:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Comment: I get this AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Answer (score 1):

Write:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

Update (complete code):

```
from datetime import datetime
import datetime as dt
import random
import re
import sys

def goodbye():
    now = datetime.now()
    now_time = now.time()

    bye = ['byee', 'see u', 'see you', 'au revoir']
    night = ['goodnight', 'gn', 'bye', 'sleep well', 'bonne nuit']

    if now_time >= dt.time(21,30) or now_time <= dt.time(4,0):
        print( random.choice(night))

    if now_time >= dt.time(4,0) or now_time <= dt.time(21,30):
        print(random.choice(bye))

goodbye()
```

Comment: Now I get NameError: global name 'time' is not defined

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers It was a mistake. I have updated my answer. thanks for noticing the issue.

Comment: @DylanLeduc this is a totally different question, and one that's easy to answer: you use a name that has indeed not been defined.  We don't know what you expect `time` to be but if you want the `time` class from the  `datetime` module you do have to import it too.

Comment: @DylanLeduc please see my updated answer. I have resolve all of your issues.

Answer (score 1):

Please use any one of this

```
import datetime
dt= datetime.datetime.now()


from datetime import datetime
dt= datetime.now()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

instead of

```
now = datetime.now()
```